# Array after initialise get BAD values [at C ]

Tags: c, arrays

first of all, I know that build array of elements without pointers it's bad coding but its part of the exercise which I can't change

edit :

```
    typedef struct st
{
    int id;
    char *name;
    int platforms;
} *Station;
```

i built an array of elements (structs) -

```
int num=X
Station statTable= malloc((num)*(sizeof(*statTable)));
```

and initialize it -

```
int i=0
while(i<num){
  station=TS->stations+i*sizeof(*station);
  station->name="blabla";
  station->id=id;
  i++
}
```

I check the array after initializing and its work, but after some iteration on the array -

```
int i=0;
while(i<num){
  station=TS->stations+i*sizeof(*station);
  printf("%d",station->id);
  i++
}
```

when TS is big struct with pointer to station which is name is stations

I get a bad value ( print screen below)and it always in the second cell, someone has an idea why it happened?
[image]

Comment: MCVE, please. Too many things can happen (or not to happen) in between.

Comment: i know but in my code after initialize its just print

Comment: (MCVE= Minimal, complete, verifiable example, i.e. something that actually compiles and can be run) Especially considering a few coding style red flags.

Comment: I'll give you an example. We don't know what `i` is initialized to. with MCVE we would know. So it is a must, not just me.

Comment: @Bizzu simply post the minimal code necessary to run this and get the output. If you can't, we can't solve your problem. It's (usually) as easy as that. And: if you reduce your code and your problem disappears, then the problem is not in what you were presenting us.

Comment: Please post what `Station` is. `Station statTable= malloc((num)*(sizeof(*statTable)));` does not reveal any expected pointer, and obfuscates `sizeof(*statTable)`. Bad practice to `typedef` pointer types.

Comment: @Weather Vane i edit and add the struct

Comment: Begin with a simple `struct` type or definition. When you want a pointer to that struct, define a pointer variable. Keep it simple and readable. Don't `typedef ` pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typedefing pointers isn't really good practice.

Bug in your code is in *pointer arithmetics*. More precisely here

```
station=TS->stations+i*sizeof(*station);
```

As we know adding `1` to pointer will move us in memory **not** one byte, but `sizeof(typeItIsAppliedOn)` bytes, in this case `sizeof(Station)` bytes.

So what you have written will move you outside of bounds pretty soon and as we know, accessing outside of bounds has undefined behavior.

This should fix it

```
station = TS->stations + i; // This will point to i-th station in memory
```

In general, you could use this semantics for better readbility

```
station = &TS->stations[i]; // Get an address of i-th element in array
```

Comment: but i want to move sizeof(*Station) and not sizeof(Station), i know its the best solution but i cant use array of pointers

Comment: It has nothing to do with array of pointers. You have simple array of structs and want to loop through every of them and set its name and id. Now you are accesing outside of bounds. Just try my solution and replace that line in both (Writing & Reading).

Comment: When a pointer is incremented, the shift is the size of what is pointed at.   In other words, `++station` gives a result that is shifted by the size of one `*station`.   If you don't understand that, you'll always muck up when using pointers - as you are demonstrating.